# Wecken versus erwecken (in übertragenem Sinn)

Tags: word-choice, synonym

Es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen *wecken* und *erwecken*, wenn sie in übertragenem Sinn benutzt werden? Beispiel:

> Seine Rede weckte / erweckte meinen Willen, Präsident zu werden.

Ist *erwecken* ein generischer Stimulus eines Gefühls und *wecken* der erste Stimulus davon (das Erzeugen eines Gefühls)?

Answer (score 1):

Allgemein ist "erwecken" austauschbar durch "wecken", hat aber gehobenes Niveau. Es klingt bedeutungsvoller und kraftvoller, es steckt einfach mehr dahinter. Große Wünsche, Tote und der Frühling werden deswegen erweckt statt einfach nur geweckt. Deswegen hört es sich auch beispielsweise ziemlich seltsam an, wenn man sagt: "Die Mutter versucht das Kind zu erwecken".
<sup>[[1]](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erwecken),[[2]](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wecken)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The prefix "er-" usually implies the start of something and emphasizes the change. With "wecken" that becomes a bit superfluous. It might be more helpful to consider the example: Die Blume blueht. vs. Die Blume erblueht. The first is a simple fact. It is not even clear that there is something changing. The blossoming is happening over a period of time. The second sentence emphasizes the change and could be translated as "the flower is starting to bloom." It is an event, a point in time rather than a period.

If you are interested in this across languages: the concept of inchoative verbs and inchoative aspects is probably a good start.